# Update ReadOnlyObservableCollection if Filter is changed

Tags: c#, dynamic-data

I derive a ReadOnlyObservable Collection by filtering a SourceList.
The filter depends on some non observable variables. 
How to ensure that the collection is updated, when the values in the filter are changed?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using DynamicData;

namespace ReadOnlyTest
{
    class DemoClass
    {
        public int Id;
        public String Name;
    }

    class Program
    {
          static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SourceList<DemoClass> SL = new SourceList<DemoClass>();
            ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DemoClass> filtered;

            int filterId = 2;        

            SL.Add(new DemoClass() { Id = 1, Name = "#1" });
            SL.Add(new DemoClass() { Id = 2, Name = "#2" });
            SL.Add(new DemoClass() { Id = 3, Name = "#3" });

            SL.Connect()
                .Filter(entr => { return entr.Id == filterId; })
                .Bind(out ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DemoClass> temp)
                .Subscribe();
            filtered = temp;

            System.Console.WriteLine("filterId = 2");

            foreach (DemoClass dc in filtered)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(dc.Name);
            }

            filterId = 3;
            System.Console.WriteLine("filterId = 3");
            foreach (DemoClass dc in filtered)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(dc.Name);
            }

            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
filterId = 2
#2
filterId = 3
#2
```

I understand, where this is coming from. Obviously the change of `filterId` which is not an `IObservable` does not trigger  and update of the filter.

However I'm searching for a solution
where when I change `filterId`, I want the SourceList to update `filtered`.

So the result would be:

```
filterId = 2
#2
filterId = 3
#3
```

after the update.

**Appliation:** In my wpf application, the filter is based on `MyRowClass SelectedRow` which is bound like:  `<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableRows}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}">`.
I couldn't find out how it is possible to trigger a refresh of a the ReadOnlyObservableCollection if `SelectedRow` is changed.

Comment: You can try to use `CollectionViewSource` to filter the data, have a look at existing thread

Comment: When you change `filterId`, you'll want the SourceList to update `filtered`, is that correct? If so, I'd go to the documentation for SourceList and look for a method to force it to execute the filter "manually".

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Thank you for your comment. Yes this is exactly what I want.    I have spend hours searching for the solution (e.g. some ´SL.Refresh()´ or ´ filtered.Update()´), but didn't succed.     Last idea I have is to generate an ´IObservable´ for every ´entr´ so that the Filter is notified on any change. But this looks seems to be much effort (Followup problems likely). And I expect that there is an easier solution.

Comment: One option would be to use a class that's properly documented instead. If you're committed for some reason to this one, [here's what I believe to be the source](https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData/blob/master/src/DynamicData/List/SourceList.cs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiple solutions:

**1) Using ReactiveUI**

[ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI) is an opinionated MVVM framework made with Reactive programming and dynamic data in mind.
Because you've mentioned that your use case is a WPF app, it is recommended to use ReactiveUI on top. Since you are using a Viewmodel property for your filter, this viewmodel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged, which with reactiveui allows you to write:

```cs
var observableFilter = this.WhenAnyValue(viewModel => viewModel.FilterId)
.Select(MakeFilter);
```

This makes an `IObservable<int>` out of the property `FilterId`, so that when your view changes the value, the WPF binding will update the viewmodel property, and the `observableFilter` produces a new value.
Add a method

```cs
private Func<DemoClass,bool> MakeFilter(int id)
{
    return demoClass => demoClass.Id == id;
}
```

this converts your value in a predicate, much like in your original example, except the filter is rebuilt for every value produced by the observable.

then in your sourcelist pipeline

```cs
    SL.Connect()
      .Filter(observableFilter)
      .Bind(out ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DemoClass> temp)
      .Subscribe();
```

This time, your filter is reapplied every time it changes

** 2) Using a subject **

Very similar to the previous solution, but doesn't use reactiveui if you dont want to.
This method will use a `Subject<T>` as the source observable for your filter.

In your viewmodel class you would write a property like this

```cs
private Subject<int> idChanged = new Subject<int>();
private int _filterId;
public FilterId 
{ 
    get => _filterId; 
    set 
    {
        _filterId = value; 
        idChanged.OnNext(value);
    } 
}
```

This `Subject<int>` is an object that is an IObservable, and its method `OnNext(int value)` will make it produce a value. This subject is then used in very much the same way as the first solution:

```cs
var observableFilter = idChanged
.Select(MakeFilter);
```

This last bit being the only difference.

I do recommend that you use the first solution and learn the reactiveui framework as it's the framework responsible for maintaining DynamicData

Comment: Thank you @Claye_L for your detailed and helpfull answer!     I could make Option 2 run.      For option 1 I need to make more investigations. WhenAnyValue(..)  was not triggering when expected. I'm new to ReactiveUI so I need some time to dive deeper an see whats going on.   THANK YOU again, BerndGit

Comment: You need something like AutoRefresh() for option one

Comment: Now also Option 1 is running.   I have removed some obsolet code and added '[Reactive]' to the filter property.     Thanks again.